# jquery rollover , show and hide

Tags: jquery, html, rollover, jquery-hover, rollovers

I have a small problem with a show and hide jquery. I was hoping someone could explain;

when you roll over image i want the btns to show and stay when you roll on the btns, (its currently flickering)

Also when you roll off the image btns go hide.

here is a demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/wdWWQ/

Thanks in advance ... Paul

code

```
/*  PICTURE BTNS SHOW.
    ===================================================================*/
    $(".show-pic-trigger").hover(function () {
        $(".show-btns-pic").show();
    }, function () {
        $(".show-btns-pic").hide();
    })
```

Comment: Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/XSc6h/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `.show-pic-trigger` to the container.

This happens because your button is blocking your anchor tag. It is always good to put the hover class in the container.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CzM3X/

Comment: appreciate your help:)

Comment: When I duplicate this code and hover over an image everything becomes highlighted. can you make it specific to each hover?

Comment: It depends on how you separate each images. Are they in different `<div class="container"></div>`?

Comment: Yes all the same, works the same just needs to display one at a time

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/CzM3X/2/ You can use `$(this).find()` for to isolate each. The placement of your two buttons on each image now depends on your CSS.

Comment: great, thats perfect !

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
/*  PICTURE BTNS SHOW.
===================================================================*/
$(".show-pic-trigger").hover(function (e) {
    $(".show-btns-pic").show();
    e.preventDefault();
}, function () {
    $(".show-btns-pic").hide(e);
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

JS FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/wdWWQ/1/

You need to use event.preventDefault() function